# Setting default fmt formatNumber maxFractionDigits for all jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is it possible to have the following tag always display 5 decimal places?

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${number}" />
```

without having to change it to

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" maxFractionDigits="5" value="${number}" />
```

basically I have so many of these and I want them all to change, I want 5 decimal places to be the default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You cam implement this by extending `fmt:formatNumber` functionality.

For this, create a class extending `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatNumberTag` to set **maxFractionDigits** to 5 by default (when not supplied).

You would also need to change the reference in your fmt tag library descriptor (tld) file to point to your own implementation.

These should be present in your jstl jar located in `WEB-INF\lib` by default .

**EDIT:** Personally, I would go for Adeel's approach of setting up a custom locale, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer is **No**,
if its of less effort then you can set 5 decimal value only in `number` at servlet

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to set a custom `Locale`, which does nothing but override `double` formatting, for the application. In this way you just need to do it in one place.

Comment: I thought of this but again he will have to replace all coding :) , its better to add  `maxFractionDigits="5" ` in this case

Comment: Cool..but won't he loose some of the Locale setting if present in system.?

Comment: @Jigar: I mean just override the things for Number format, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, no. But you can install/use a text editor which has kind of a *Find And Replace In All Files* function. [Editplus](http://www.editplus.com/) for example. I believe Notepad++ is also able to.

Assuming Editplus, just open all JSP files in the editor. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Fill in the following

> Find what: `<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value`
>   Replace with: `<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" maxFractionDigits="5" value`

Click the *All open files* option in *Replace all range* and then click *Replace All*.

[image]

That's it.

Choose *File > Save All* to save them all. Press if necessary <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh your Eclipse/Netbeans/whatever project to refresh the files.